# SQL - re.split: BY comma THEN space

Tags: sql

I want to split the following string into City, Province, Postal Code.
Thank you so much for the help!!!!

Description: Split by comma, then split by space only once.

```
A = 'Vaughan, ON L6D 9X0'
```

Result:

```
(Vaughan, ON, L6D9X0)
```

Attempt:

```
re.split(',|/s[1]', A)
```

Comment: tag the RDBMS (MySQL, MS SQL Server, Orcale, etc...) which u r using.

Answer (score 0):

IF, You are working with `Microsoft` `SQL Server`, then you could use  `SUBSTRING`() &`CHARINDEX`() function to find specific `Char` index to split the `string` values.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(<column>, 1, CHARINDEX(',', <column>)-1) City,
       SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(<column>, CHARINDEX(' ', <column>)+1, LEN(<column>)), 1, CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(<column>, CHARINDEX(' ', <column>)+1, LEN(<column>)))) Province,
       SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(<column>, CHARINDEX(' ', <column>)+1, LEN(<column>)), CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(<column>, CHARINDEX(' ', <column>)+1, LEN(<column>)))+1, LEN(<column>)) [Postal Code];
```

**Desired Output :**

```
City     Province    Postal Code
Vaughan  ON          L6D 9X0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

This selected the values into rows, maybe you can **pivot** the cte **C2** same in order to get it as columns

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
  SELECT
    1 Seq,
    'Vaughan, ON L6D 9X0' "Txt"

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    Seq+1 "Seq",
    Txt = CASE WHEN Txt LIKE '% %'
              THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(Txt,CHARINDEX(' ',Txt),LEN(Txt))))
            ELSE NULL END
    FROM CTE
      WHERE ISNULL(txt,'')<>''
),C2
AS
(
SELECT
  CASE Seq
    WHEN 1 THEN 'City'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Province'
    ELSE 'PostalCode' END "Head",
  CASE Seq
    WHEN 1
      THEN SUBSTRING(Txt,1,CHARINDEX(',',Txt)-1)
    WHEN 2 
      THEN SUBSTRING(Txt,1,CHARINDEX(' ',Txt)-1)
    ELSE Txt END "Txt"
  FROM CTE
    WHERE Seq<4
)
SELECT
  *
  FROM C2;
```

If you have multiple rows that need to be parsed in the same way then, you can give the same in the select statement of 1st CTE and in that case, the logic for Seq on the first select might need to be changed. As per the above, the output will be as follows

[image: Sample Output]

Answer (score 0):

With Postgres you can do that using:

```
select split_part(a, ',', 1) as city,
       left(trim(split_part(a,',',2)), strpos(trim(split_part(a,',',2)), ' ')),
       substr(trim(split_part(a,',',2)) as province, strpos(trim(split_part(a,',',2)), ' ') + 1) as postal_code
from the_table;
```

This can be made a bit more readable by using a derived table:

```
select city,
       left(second_part, strpos(second_part, ' ')) as province,
       substr(second_part, strpos(second_part, ' ') + 1) as postal_code
from (
  select split_part(a, ',', 1) as city,
         trim(split_part(a, ',', 2)) as second_part
  from the_table
) t
```